# Error in ServiceWrapper

Tags: java, android, rest

To call the web services, I created a listview in the xml layout, I gave internet permission and I used the code which had be given in the stackoverflow,

```
 HttpHost target = new HttpHost(ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST,ServiceWrapper.SERVER_PORT);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("/list");
    String result=null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
      HttpResponse response=client.execute(target, get);
      entity = response.getEntity();
      result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
      if (entity!=null)
       try {
        entity.consumeContent();
       } catch (IOException e) {}
     }
     return return;
}
```

Xml layout code is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>
```

but here I am getting an error in ServiceWrapper, do I have to include any other classes? Any ideas?

Comment: Show your error log. What mean HttpGet("/list")?

Comment: m getting error in the 1st line of code itself as Service Wrapper cannot be resolved, and giving me the options to create a class, interface, constants, enum, local variable etc

Comment: It is mean that something wrong in your syntax. Post all your code